# JS после import не вызывается функция

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день! Столкнулся вот с такой вещью как модули. 
Есть импорт:

```
import {films} from './films.js';
```

Есть функция которая использует модуль (вызывается по нажатию кнопки):

```
function out() {
    alert(films[0].title);
}
```

Как мне использовать модуль в функции и почему мне пишет, что она не используется если есть вызов по нажатию:

`<button class="btn" onclick="out()">ok</button>`

П.С. указал тип скрипта в HTML файле как модуль:

`<script src="script.js" rel="script" type="module"></script>`

Comment: import {films} from './films.js'; и затем window.films = films. Но вообще обработчики лучше через addEventListener добавлять

Comment: где был сделал импорт и где объявлена функция out?

Answer (score 0):

Cпасибо Dantessss за ответ! С помощью addEventListener все заработало

```
import {films} from './films.js';
function out() {
    alert(films[0].title);
}
elem.addEventListener("click", out);
```

Comment: так проблема было в том что почему он не работает внутри html и показывает `not used` разве нет?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов ну не видел он ее внутри модуля :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это то понятно но все равно я думал есть какой то экстраординарное решение для этого вопроса.Жаль...

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов есть, window.out = out; :)